# Fast Estimation of Random Effects with Measurement Error

Tags: random-effects-model, measurement-error, stan

Let $Y_{i}$~$Normal( Z_{i} , \sigma_{i}^{2})$ and $Z_{i}$~$Normal(0,\tau^{2})$, where $Y_{i}$ is a measurement, $\sigma_{i}$ is known measurement error,  $Z_{i}$ is the unknown latent variable I want to measure, and $\tau$ has some sort of flat prior.

If you know $\tau$, then there are straightforward conjugates for $E(Z_{i})$ and $Var(Z_{i})$. Right now I'm using STAN to calculate posterior mean and variances, but that seems like radical overkill. Any suggestions on a fast/easy approach (preferably in R) to deal with these kind of models?

Comment: This does seem right up Stan's alley. Just beware the flat prior

Comment: Overkill in what sense? Installing a C++ compiler to use with (R)Stan is a bit of a hurdle, but if you have already overcome that one-time cost, then using Stan for the model you described ought to be pretty simple and also efficient if you express each `Z` as the product of `tau` and a standard normal variate.